# Passing data parameters on SSRS using Snowflake data source

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssrs-2012

We are migrating the SQL Server SSRS reports to Snowflake; I have a question about parameters in SQL version -

```
select * 
from tbname 
where xtype in (@xtype)
```

How to write this in the Snowflake version?

Comment: I think you’ll need to update your question to provide a fuller explanation e.g. what is @xtype, how is it being set, what value(s) can it take, etc

Comment: @ is used to create a parameter in ssrs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: select * 
from tbname 
where xtype in (@xtype) - This is SQL version which we create generally for SSRS to accept parameters , what's the snowflake syntax for the above code.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to pass multiple values to Snowflake from the report using ODBC driver:

- `?` used as a parameter placeholder
- multiple values are provided as a single concatenated string, therefore in the main query they are splitted [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM TBNAME
WHERE XTYPE IN (
   SELECT t.value
   FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(?, '^')) AS t
)
```

---

The direct translation of SQL Server version will not work and error out:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBNAME
WHERE XTYPE IN (?)
```

> Cannot add multi value query parameter '?' for dataset 'TBNAME' because it is not supported by the data extension.

---

Snowflake setup:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST.TBNAME AS 
SELECT 1 AS XTYPE, 'A' AS col, 'GB' AS country UNION 
SELECT 2 AS XTYPE, 'B' AS col, 'BE' AS country UNION 
SELECT 3 AS XTYPE, 'C' AS col, 'CH' AS country;
```

---

Report side:

Parameter:

[image]

Sample input values:

[image]

Dataset definition:

[image]

Dataset parameter (expression: `=JOIN(Parameters!Param_XType.Value, "^")`):

[image]

Report test:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake you set a variable using the SET command and then reference it in SQL statements by prefixing it with $ e.g.

```
set (min, max)=(40, 70);

select $min;

select avg(salary) from emp where age between $min and $max;
```

This is documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html

Comment: I need for SSRS

Comment: I don’t understand your last comment: you said you already have this working in SSRS and your question was about moving to Snowflake  - so why are you now saying that you need it for SSRS? I think you need to update your question with a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Indeed... weird. Upvoted to balance things.

Answer (score 0):

I would really appreciate if you share details on which approach are you followed to Passing data parameters on SSRS using Snowflake data source.

Comment: Please leave a comment, without commeting as an asnwer. Thanks (:

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35660940)