# Errors when using start and end dates as parameters in MS Report Builder via Snowflake DB

Tags: reporting-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Microsoft Report Builder version 15.0.19914.0 with Snowflake Dataset via ODBC connection. This is my working query which works perfectly with MS Report Builder

```
WITH calls_presented AS (
  SELECT
    "Resource"."resourcename",
    COUNT(DISTINCT "ContactCallDetail"."sessionid") AS presented
  FROM
    "ContactCallDetail"
    JOIN "AgentConnectionDetail"
      ON "ContactCallDetail"."sessionid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."sessionid"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."sessionseqnum" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."sessionseqnum"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."profileid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."profileid"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."nodeid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."nodeid"
    JOIN "Resource"
      ON "AgentConnectionDetail"."resourceid" = "Resource"."resourceid"
  WHERE
    "ContactCallDetail"."startdatetime" BETWEEN '2023-04-09 00:00:00' AND '2023-04-15 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY
    "Resource"."resourcename"
),
calls_handled AS (
  SELECT
    "Resource"."resourcename",
    COUNT(DISTINCT "ContactCallDetail"."sessionid") AS handled
  FROM
    "ContactCallDetail"
    JOIN "AgentConnectionDetail"
      ON "ContactCallDetail"."sessionid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."sessionid"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."sessionseqnum" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."sessionseqnum"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."profileid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."profileid"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."nodeid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."nodeid"
    JOIN "Resource"
      ON "AgentConnectionDetail"."resourceid" = "Resource"."resourceid"
  WHERE
    "ContactCallDetail"."startdatetime" BETWEEN '2023-04-09 00:00:00' AND '2023-04-15 23:59:59'
    AND "ContactCallDetail"."contactdisposition" = 2
    AND "AgentConnectionDetail"."talktime" > 0
  GROUP BY
    "Resource"."resourcename"
),
login_time AS (
  SELECT
    "Resource"."resourcename",
    ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "AgentStateDetail"."eventdatetime" < '2023-04-09 00:00:00' THEN "AgentStateDetail"."eventdatetime" END) / COUNT(*) * 1.0, 2) AS login_percentage
  FROM
    "AgentStateDetail"
    JOIN "Resource"
      ON "AgentStateDetail"."agentid" = "Resource"."resourceid"
      AND "AgentStateDetail"."profileid" = "Resource"."profileid"
  WHERE
    "AgentStateDetail"."eventtype" = 1
  GROUP BY
    "Resource"."resourcename"
)
SELECT
  calls_handled."resourcename" AS AgentName,
  COALESCE(calls_handled.handled, 0) AS CallsHandled,
  COALESCE(calls_presented.presented, 0) AS CallsPresented,
  CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(calls_presented.presented, 0) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND(COALESCE(calls_handled.handled, 0) / COALESCE(calls_presented.presented, 0), 2)
  END AS HandleRatio,
  login_time.login_percentage AS LoginBeforeTopHour
FROM
  calls_handled
  FULL JOIN calls_presented
    ON calls_handled."resourcename" = calls_presented."resourcename"
  LEFT JOIN login_time
    ON calls_handled."resourcename" = login_time."resourcename"
ORDER BY
  calls_handled."resourcename"
```

Now once I switch the start and end date to datetime type parameters as in the below query

```
WITH calls_presented AS (
  SELECT
    "Resource"."resourcename",
    COUNT(DISTINCT "ContactCallDetail"."sessionid") AS presented
  FROM
    "ContactCallDetail"
    JOIN "AgentConnectionDetail"
      ON "ContactCallDetail"."sessionid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."sessionid"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."sessionseqnum" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."sessionseqnum"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."profileid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."profileid"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."nodeid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."nodeid"
    JOIN "Resource"
      ON "AgentConnectionDetail"."resourceid" = "Resource"."resourceid"
  WHERE
    "ContactCallDetail"."startdatetime" BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  GROUP BY
    "Resource"."resourcename"
),
calls_handled AS (
  SELECT
    "Resource"."resourcename",
    COUNT(DISTINCT "ContactCallDetail"."sessionid") AS handled
  FROM
    "ContactCallDetail"
    JOIN "AgentConnectionDetail"
      ON "ContactCallDetail"."sessionid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."sessionid"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."sessionseqnum" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."sessionseqnum"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."profileid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."profileid"
      AND "ContactCallDetail"."nodeid" = "AgentConnectionDetail"."nodeid"
    JOIN "Resource"
      ON "AgentConnectionDetail"."resourceid" = "Resource"."resourceid"
  WHERE
    "ContactCallDetail"."startdatetime" BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND "ContactCallDetail"."contactdisposition" = 2
    AND "AgentConnectionDetail"."talktime" > 0
  GROUP BY
    "Resource"."resourcename"
),
login_time AS (
  SELECT
    "Resource"."resourcename",
    ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN "AgentStateDetail"."eventdatetime" < @StartDate THEN "AgentStateDetail"."eventdatetime" END) / COUNT(*) * 1.0, 2) AS login_percentage
  FROM
    "AgentStateDetail"
    JOIN "Resource"
      ON "AgentStateDetail"."agentid" = "Resource"."resourceid"
      AND "AgentStateDetail"."profileid" = "Resource"."profileid"
  WHERE
    "AgentStateDetail"."eventtype" = 1
  GROUP BY
    "Resource"."resourcename"
)
SELECT
  calls_handled."resourcename" AS AgentName,
  COALESCE(calls_handled.handled, 0) AS CallsHandled,
  COALESCE(calls_presented.presented, 0) AS CallsPresented,
  CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(calls_presented.presented, 0) = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND(COALESCE(calls_handled.handled, 0) / COALESCE(calls_presented.presented, 0), 2)
  END AS HandleRatio,
  login_time.login_percentage AS LoginBeforeTopHour
FROM
  calls_handled
  FULL JOIN calls_presented
    ON calls_handled."resourcename" = calls_presented."resourcename"
  LEFT JOIN login_time
    ON calls_handled."resourcename" = login_time."resourcename"
ORDER BY
  calls_handled."resourcename"
```

I get the following error :

```
An error occurred while executing the query.
ERROR [42000] SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 15 at position 48 unexpected '@StartDate'
syntax error line 15 at position 63 unexpected '@EndDate'
syntax error line 33 at position 48 unexpected '@StartDate'
syntax error line 33 at position 63 unexpected '@EndDate'
syntax error line 42 at position 72 unexpected '@StartDate'
```

I did try setting up expressions for the parameters like `=FormatDateTime(Parameters!StartDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)` and `=FormatDateTime(Parameters!EndDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)` as well. Since I thought this issue might be due to a date time format mismatch with MS Report Builder and Snowflake. Unfortunately that was not the solution. The `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` parameters are setup with `DateTime` data type in MS Report Builder.

Comment: It complains about the syntax of calling the variables. It should be defiend as eg: ```SET StartDate = '2023-04-09 00:00:00'``` and in the query you call it as: ```$StartDate```

Comment: I tried changing @StartDate and @EndDate to $StartDate and $EndDate as you mentioned. Getting error `Error [02000] SQL Compilation Error: Error line 15 at position 48 Session variable '$STARTDATE' does not exist `.
Also there is no issue when I'm using the query with specified start and end dates i.e. '2023-04-09 00:00:00' and '2023-04-15 23:59:59'. But only issue when we chose to do the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC expects `?` for parameters:

```
WHERE "ContactCallDetail"."startdatetime" BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

should be:

```
WHERE "ContactCallDetail"."startdatetime" BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: How would I differentiate the `StartDate` and `EndDate` if I'm using `?` and `?` as the parameters? Ex : I have setup `StartDate` and `EndDate` as `DateTime` type so that user can select the date and populate the report.

Comment: Positional notation, try placing `?` 4 times one per each occurrence and then bind them at parameters tab

Comment: @JoanneAngelia  Great to hear it :) If you ever need to use parameter for `IN (@var)` then https://stackoverflow.com/a/74910787/5070879 may be useful

Comment: @JoanneAngelia - you could also DECLARE your own parameters that repeat. `DECLARE @StartDate DATE = ?` It makes it easier when you have several that are used multiple times.