# Can you Pass a parameter to an anonymous block?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an anonymous block of code that works when I define the parameters for testing. However, what I really need to do is be able to pass something into it.

In the 4th line of code, which is commented out, you see a ? mark, which is how I was passing parameters when using session variables. This of course limited me to 256 bits, I need way more than that.

I am not sure how Snowflake is even an enterprise company with such a limit, So I began looking at the 16 MB limit on the anonymous block and using VARCHAR. The script below runs, but as I said it's hard-coded. I wasn't sure if maybe there were different variables, like $? or something weird snowflake uses for inside these, similar to how they use = to assign session but := for in blocks. Ultimately, it's getting dropped in SSRS, so the user can click "All" without it failing because there are 50 items with 6 characters on the list.(or other things like that)

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE 
    vParameter1 VARCHAR(16777216) := '700,145,138,159';
    --vParameter1 VARCHAR(16777216) := ?;
    res RESULTSET DEFAULT (SELECT 0 AS LOC_ID, 'all' LOC_NAME);
BEGIN
res := (
SELECT    0 AS Loc_ID
        

UNION ALL

SELECT TO_NUMBER(table1.VALUE) AS Loc_ID
FROM TABLE(SPLIT_to_table(:vParameter1,',')) AS table1 

);
RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
$$;
```

Example of Fields manual edit due to anonymous block hiding column names.
[image]

Comment: Hi - can you explain in more detail how “ Ultimately, it's getting dropped in SSRS”? How are you planning to get SSRS to run an anonymous block of code in a worksheet? Are you actually trying to write a UDF that SSRS can execute?

Comment: Well I kind of went down a rabbit hole. I had the script working with ? mark and was able to pass the parameters from SSRS into it. However, This was using session variables which are only 256 bits, our users often click ALL or just select so many things its more than 256 bits. So I tried to define a variable length and ended up with the above. But now I cannot pass the parameters in (or see the columns coming out) The 2nd I got around I think, by manually defining the fields. The Parameters though is a no go. So like in SSRS @Paremeter1 is a list of 200 locations IDs for example.

Comment: Ok - but you haven’t explained how you are getting SSRS to run an anonymous block of Snowflake SQL, which is really what my question was. Where/how are your storing this SQL, how are you getting SSRS to execute it, how are you consuming the data it’s returning, etc?

Comment: Right, so using the script above I put it in SSRS. I get an error because it doesn't know the columns to return. I do though, so I define them in the Fields section of the data set and now I can get it to work for that query as with hard-coded values. Now I am trying to dynamizes it by using a parameter in place of the hard-code.  Before when doing this I found Snowflake used ? then setup the parameters or a JOIN(Parameter,",") expression for multi value parameters. So I tried this, but once I removed '700...159' and put ? it through an error at the ? "unnamed bind in SQL stored procedure.

Comment: It looks like the real question here is not related Snowflake but how to pass multiple arguments to query from SSRS `SELECT TO_NUMBER(table1.VALUE) AS Loc_ID
FROM TABLE(SPLIT_to_table(<input_from_SSRS>,',')) AS table1 `. For that you do not really need Snowflake Scripting block. [Passing data parameters on SSRS using Snowflake data source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74910787/5070879)

Comment: This is exactly how I am doing it, and why I have the split table in my example. The problem is. For long code with multi parameters there are so many "?" it gets messy and confusing. The code I am working on now has 15 "?" if I do it this way, but only 6 actual parameters. So I was try to assign the ? only once without making a CTE or something for every parameter. Hence using the SET=Parameter, but this limits to 256 bit. Then I went to blocks. It sounds like Blocks are impossible so that is OK. I will go back to a CTE per multi parameter route and see how that pans out.